# GPUImage filter chaining multiple arbitrary GPUImageFilters

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, gpuimage

We are building a few photo adjustment tools, most are structured this way:

- original image
- GPUImageLookupFilter creates a new image
- GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter then blends the image generated by GPUImageLookupFilter with the original image

Each adjustment has code like this:

```
var blendFilter = GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter()
var mix = getValue() // assume this exists
blendFilter.mix = mix

var styledImageSource = getImageSource() // assume returns a GPUImagePicture
styledImageSource.addTarget(blendFilter, atTextureLocation: 1)
blendFilter.useNextFrameForImageCapture()
styledImageSource.processImage()

return blendFilter
```

At the end, if there's only one blend, we run this code:

```
var originalImage = getOriginalImage() // assume gets an UIImage that we want to filter
filter = getBlendFilter() // assume this calls the above and gets a blendFilter
var finalImage = filter.imageByFilteringImage(originalImage)
```

The above finalImage is great and blended.

But now, we have a bunch of different adjustment tools that do various things. Let's assume some are blending, but they need to do do a last imageByFilteringImage. We want to chain these up, so that we don't create images between each one, and would like to chain them instead.

Here's a few concepts we've tried:

- Loop through each one and save an intermediate UIImage between each, that works but is slow and kills memory after a few adjustments.
- Try filter chaining a lot of the blend filters together. It only applies the last filter to the final image. We're unable to figure out to "save" an intermediate image in between each.

I'm thinking there's another way, maybe Filter Groups?

How would we best go about this?

Thanks!